# Protect my java and angularjs code after deployment to client server

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, angularjs, cassandra

I have developed a distributed commercial application which sits in a number of client's IT infrastructure.

The app includes a mysql db, Cassandra db, various java backend engine and a angular frontend.

As i understand it, protecting my code from reverse engineering, copying etc is  impossible. 
3 questions on my technical options:

1. Is obfuscation my only option for ng war and java jar files?
2. What should i do with my mysql and cassandra db to protect it from investigation and copying? (I cant encrypt its data due to performance hit)
3. If i was to redevelop my backend in future what language/tech wpuld accomplish better security against reverse engineering and/or copying?

Comment: Please tag this appropriately as `angular` or `angularjs` not both

Comment: Ok. I wasnt aware of the diff in the tags, i will delete one

Comment: do you have on prem deployment or on cloud ?

Comment: On client prem deployment. I would ideally like to wrap everything in one service but prob not possible. Would docker offer any advantages here?